# ¿Por qué no puedo usar mis protocolos, qué hago mal?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Este es mi código, veo los métodos y me pide crearlos, pero no ejecuta nada.

```
viewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()<SalvatoreAndlerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   ViewController2 *theInstance = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [theInstance loadFunc];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)onFound:(NSString *)message{
    NSLog(@"work2");
    NSLog(@"work ond found %@",message);
}


@end



ViewController2.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SalvatoreAndlerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)onFound:(NSString *)message;

@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (weak) id<SalvatoreAndlerDelegate> delegate;
-(void)loadFunc;

@end

ViewController2.m
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.delegate onFound:@"sergio encontrado"];
    NSLog(@"start");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)loadFunc{
    NSLog(@"start func");
    [self.delegate onFound:@"sergio encontrado"];
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Hola @Salvatore. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor describe qué estás intentando hacer, ¿dónde falla? ¿Cuál es el error puntual que te muestra? ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta para agregarlo. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

En ningún sitio has asignado valor a delegate. Lo creas, pero delegate estará a nil. en el Viewcontroller tienes que darle valor

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   ViewController2 *theInstance = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
   theInstance.delegate = self;
   [theInstance loadFunc];
}
```

De esta forma cuando en theInstance hagas el [self.delegate onFound:@"sergio encontrado"]; delegate estará apuntando al Viewcontroller principal

Excelente, ya funciona correctamente jaja. gracias nuevamente.